# Ignoring empty value fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As of Elastic Search 7, a breaking change has been introduced that causes Elastic Search to throw the following exception: [Link here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_accessing_missing_document_values_will_throw_an_error).

> doc['field'].value will throw an exception if the document is missing a value for the field field.

I have an application that builds several different aggregation queries like the one below.

```
{
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "must":[
           {
              "terms":{
                 "state":[
                    "pending",
                    "queued",
                    "deferred"
                 ]
              }
           },
           {
              "terms":{
                 "tenant_tag":[
                    "prod"
                 ]
              }
           }
          ]
     }
  },
  "aggs":{
     "count":{
        "cardinality":{
           "script":"doc['user_id'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id'].value"
        }
     }
  },
  "size":0
}
```

For the sake of my application, I still need to include the counts of documents whose field values might be empty. Is there a way to include those and ignore the exception thrown by ElasticSearch? Or, better yet, specifically include those somewhere in the query above?

I've tried adding the following exists blocks to this query, and it *does* work, however the count is off because of the documents with empty fields.

```
{
  "exists":{
    "field":"user_id"
  }
},
  {
    "exists":{
      "field":"campaign_id"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is this:

```
 "count":{
    "cardinality":{
       "script":"doc['user_id'].size() > 0 && doc['campaign_id'].size() > 0 ? doc['user_id'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id'].value : 'N/A'"
    }
 }
```

You're gonna get the number of documents with unique user_id/campaign_id pairs. Moreover, all the documents that miss either of the two fields will be counted as 1 (i.e. `N/A`).

Adding the aggregation below you can get the count of how many docs don't have either field:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "state": [
              "pending",
              "queued",
              "deferred"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "tenant_tag": [
              "prod"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "missing": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "user_id"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "campaign_id"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": "doc['user_id.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['campaign_id.keyword'].size() > 0 ? doc['user_id.keyword'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id.keyword'].value : 'N/A'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when replacing the script with your suggestion and without the exists clauses in there, I am still not receiving counts that are significantly off. This script seems to produce the same count as keeping the exists in both. Any ideas why?

Comment: You don't have errors anymore though. Also without having any idea of what counts your expecting, it's hard to understand... Also are you sure what the cardinality aggregation does?

Comment: Or do you simply want to know how many documents don't have the user_id and or campaign_id fields? Not sure what else you'd want to know for those

Comment: It wasn't erroring with the exists either, however the count with the exists compared to without is about 8500 documents off. I need the count to include all documents even if the doc[user_id] or doc[campaign_id] is empty

Comment: Then you won't be able to do it with the cardinality agg, but we can add another one that gives you that count. I've updated my answer, please try it out, but don't specify any exists query in the query part, though, or that won't work.

Comment: I'm no expert at ES like yourself, any chance you could bundle this answer up in one nice query? Think i'm getting them confused with them being split.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

##### Using the "missing" argument in the "script" field of the "cardinality" aggregation in Elasticsearch

Include documents that might contain empty field values while excluding documents that do not.

Updated Query:

```
{
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "must":[
           {
              "terms":{
                 "state":[
                    "pending",
                    "queued",
                    "deferred"
                 ]
              }
           },
           {
              "terms":{
                 "tenant_tag":[
                    "prod"
                 ]
              }
           }
          ]
     }
  },
  "aggs":{
     "count":{
        "cardinality":{
           "script":{
              "source": "if (doc['user_id'].size() == 0 || doc['campaign_id'].size() == 0) { return 'missing'; } else { return doc['user_id'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id'].value; }",
              "lang": "painless"
           },
           "missing": "missing"
        }
     }
  },
  "size":0
}
```

Comment: The missing argument has the same effect as my `N/A` return value actually.